# Pulling Data from S3 through spark streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-streaming

I am trying to pull data from S3 using Spark streaming. But i am getting the error as "Error finding new files".

```
    17/08/22 08:21:37 WARN FileInputDStream: Error finding new files
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef$.length$extension(ArrayOps.scala:192)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.length(ArrayOps.scala:192)
    at scala.collection.SeqLike$class.size(SeqLike.scala:106)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.size(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.mutable.Builder$class.sizeHint(Builder.scala:69)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuilder.sizeHint(ArrayBuilder.scala:22)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.builder$1(TraversableLike.scala:230)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FileInputDStream.findNewFiles(FileInputDStream.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FileInputDStream.compute(FileInputDStream.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.compute(MappedDStream.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FilteredDStream.compute(FilteredDStream.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.generateJob(ForEachDStream.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:116)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.generateJobs(DStreamGraph.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:247)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.generateJobs(JobGenerator.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
17/08/22 08:21:37 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1503415294000 ms:
```

Following is the code extract that i am using:

```
 SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName("kafka-sandbox")
                .setMaster("local[*]");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(2000));
        sc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", "AccessKey");
        sc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", "SecretKey");

       JavaDStream<String> data = ssc.textFileStream("s3://dm/unencrypted/");

       JavaDStream<String> lines = data.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>(){
           public Boolean call(String line){
               return line.contains("resource");
           }
       });
       lines.print();

       ssc.start();
       ssc.awaitTermination();
```

I need to pick up all the files from the S3 bucket and use spark streaming to pull them find the appropriate files which contain the word resource and print them.

Please help!

Comment: did you try using a wildcard at the end of your input path? Just curious if that helps.

Comment: @TaylerJones The error is gone but then, i cannot see any result! Though my file contains the word resources plus i have a print statement!

Comment: unfortunately I don't have much experience with Java API nor un-structured streaming. I would probably start by removing the filter and just getting the contents of the file to print.

Comment: No problem. Thanks @TaylerJones